# @tailwind base does not work when using router.refresh

Tags: tailwind-css, next.js13

I took the cookie value from root layout.tsx to implement dark mode during development as next13js, made code to change the background and color value from global css, put the Darkcode.tsx component in and set the cookie value to change from Darkcode.tsx to onClick. In addition, router refresh was used to update the page when the cookie value was changed.

The Darkmde change works well, but we found that the text of the

tag briefly grew and then decreased again, just as the @tailwind base applied to global.css was released.
In addition, the size of the svg icons also increases and then decreases again.

why...?

here is my codes please help me..

```
[root layout.tsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGhlH.png)
[global css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMhpT.png)
[Darkmode tsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nEcq.png)
[folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejEJK.png)
```

I changed it from styled component to tailwind, but I thought the styled component setting was a problem, so I annotated all the setting codes...